# URL rewriting in shopping cart site best practice?

Tags: url-rewriting, shopping-cart

I am building an eCommerce web site with a shopping cart. 
Each item in this portal belongs to one category. So when I display an item, in an item details page, which is the best practice to create the URL from the following?

```
1. <domain>/<item-category>/<item-name>
2. <domain>/<item-name>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for URL rewriting are (a) to make URL's more human readable and (b) to make the URL's more search engine friendly.  In this respect, whether you include the category probably makes little difference to humans if they can distinguish the product from the name alone.  Adding category might make the links more understandable to a search engine, but there can be a penalty for depth of link too.  With just three sections, you should be OK, but in instances where you have a deeper hierarchy, you might look at joining the item category and name with a separator that isn't '/', such as '-'.

Comment: Thanks.. It's just three sections. I'll be using the first one.